# How can I align two input fields of two forms in same line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, web

Following are two forms from a html page

```
<form method="get" action="search/s" id="number">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
                <input  type="text" id="regNo" name="regNo" size="30" maxLength="50" > or     
        </div>      
    </form>           

    <form method="get" action="search/l" id="name"> 

                <input  type="text" id="studentName" name="studentName" size="30" maxLength="50" >

    </form>
```

I want both the fields to be in one line one after other and center aligned. How can I do this?

Comment: have u tried 
#number{
float:left;
}

?

Comment: Could you give me an example with some code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them together in an extra container element, for example a `div`, with `text-align:center`. Then just give `display:inline-block` to the `form` elements to override the default `block` rendering which forces them onto new lines.

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22o8v662/).

Comment: I would like to know does using containers and css be a performance issue in UI side. Performance with respect to browser loading and DOM. Just curious.

Comment: Not at this level. Use hundreds of thousands and it might get statistically significant in the end. More likely millions are needed to make it measurable. And most likely you'll still need them anyway to make it render correctly with that many elements.

Comment: If you're curious about performance - hit 'inspect element' somewhere in the middle of Facebook and ask yourself how fast that still loads.

Answer (score 1):

You want to omit the div around the first input - it's display: block by nature and blocks align on a new row automatically. The .container div should have a fixed width (either or px or %) for the centering to work.

```
<div class="container">
<form method="get" action="search/s" id="number">

            <input  type="text" id="regNo" name="regNo" size="30" maxLength="50" > or     

</form>           

<form method="get" action="search/l" id="name"> 

            <input  type="text" id="studentName" name="studentName" size="30" maxLength="50" >

</form>
</div>
<style>

    .container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You're doing some very evil things here. First of all, `display:inline` is, for natural block elements like `form`, quite dangerous. It will go right in this case, but usually you should prefer `inline-block`. Secondly, you're assuming a fixed width for the content, which is severely limiting and unneeded.

Comment: I edited the answer, so the form isn't inline. 

What seems kind of evil to me is text-align: center of input fields - I would rather have them both on fixed with (ie 50%) and the container may be also fixed on ie. 75% of the mother element - this should do nicely with responsive designs...

Comment: `text-align` is used to control the rendering of `inline` elements within a container. `input` elements are `inline` by default, nothing evil about using them that way. The suggestions about how to improve the layout are nice, but not relevant for the question at hand which is more easily and flexibly solved in other ways.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Let me just change that to the easiest soulution. I specified the input display: inline in case it has been manipulated with before...

Answer (score -1):

you simply need to float left first form.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6vpvnaw4/) example how u asked

```
#number{
 float:left;
}
```